# Arcpy: calculating a field based on feature class geometry, eg 'if FC =="POINT" calculate xy coord

Tags: arcpy, coordinates, fields-attributes

I have a script that populates new fields based on user input.  I would like it to also add the XY coordinates in DD if the Feature Class is a point feature, else, it moves on to the next command.
I would have thought that using the Describe function with an IF statement that it would work (see code at line 32).  However, although I don't receive an error message, the fields are not populated.  The script works fine without the IF statement on a point featureClass but (obviously) fails if it is not a point feature class.  I've placed the entire code in just in case.
Any thoughts?

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HQ_Std_fields.py
# Created on: 2014-04-14 14:49:12.00000

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "CURRENT"
from time import strftime
import numpy
# strftime("%y%m%d")
#--------------DEFINE VARIABLES---------------
    in_featureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    de_classe = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    de_objet = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
    de_source = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
    de_remarque = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
#de_traitment = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
#num_sequence = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)

#-----------------DEFINE EXPRESSIONS-----------------
ClaExpression = str(de_classe)
objExpression = str(de_objet)
deSouExpression = str(de_source)
coDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
deRemExpression = str(de_remarque)


#----------------------------------------------------
#add fields xDD and yDD with WGS84 spatial reference
#populate xDD and yDD with decimal degree coordinates.
#source: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29478/how-to-calculate-xy-coordinates-in-decimal-degrees-from-projected-dataset-in-mod
#source: http://gisstudio.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/calc-the-latlong-of-a-point-in-python-using-new-arcpy-tools/

desc = arcpy.Describe(in_featureClass)
type = desc.shapeType
if type == "POINT":
    sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
    updCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(in_featureClass,"",sr)
    for row6 in updCursor:
        pnt = row6.Shape.getPart(0)
        row6.xDD = pnt.X
        row6.yDD = pnt.Y
        updCursor.updateRow(row6)
    del updCursor, row6

#-------------------------------------------------------
ClasseTemp = de_classe
for ClasseAbrev in ClasseTemp:



#reads feature class name
#determins geometry and plots xy coordinates for points and centroid for polygons and lines?
#reads class abbreviation and populates class field
#-------------------------------------
    if ClasseTemp == "activite autochtone":
        ClasseAbrev = "Activite autochtone"
    elif ClasseTemp == "agriculture":
        ClasseAbrev = "Agriculture"
    elif ClasseTemp == "aire designee":
        ClasseAbrev = "Aire designee"

    if ClasseTemp == "archeologie et patrimoine":
        ClasseAbrev = "Archeologie et patrimoine"
    elif ClasseTemp == "batiment":
        ClasseAbrev = "Batiment"
    elif ClasseTemp == "aire designee":
        ClasseAbrev = "Aire designee"

    if ClasseTemp == "equipement":
        ClasseAbrev = "Equipement"
    elif ClasseTemp == "faune aquatique":
        ClasseAbrev = "Faune aquatique"
    elif ClasseTemp == "faune terrestre":
        ClasseAbrev = "Faune terrestre"

    if ClasseTemp == "faune avienne":
        ClasseAbrev = "Faune avienne"
    elif ClasseTemp == "mesure d'attenuation":
        ClasseAbrev = "Mesure d'attenuation"
    elif ClasseTemp == "milieu biologique":
        ClasseAbrev = "Milieu biologique"

    if ClasseTemp == "milieu humain":
        ClasseAbrev = "Milieu humain"
    elif ClasseTemp == "modele numerique":
        ClasseAbrev = "Modele numerique"
    elif ClasseTemp == "milieu physique":
        ClasseAbrev = "Milieu physique"


    if ClasseTemp == "modele":
        ClasseAbrev = "Modele"
    elif ClasseTemp == "vegetation":
        ClasseAbrev = "Vegetation"
    elif ClasseTemp == "voie de communication":
        ClasseAbrev = "Voie de communication"

    if ClasseTemp == "donnee auxiliare":
        ClasseAbrev = "Donnee auxiliare"
    elif ClasseTemp == "hypsometrie":
        ClasseAbrev = "Hypsometrie"
    elif ClasseTemp == "hydrographie":
        ClasseAbrev = "Hydrographie"

#--------------CALCULATE TEXT FIELDS---------------------------
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_featureClass,["de_cla"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None or row[0] == ' ':
            row[0] = de_classe
            cursor.updateRow(row)

del row
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_featureClass,["de_obj"]) as cursor:
    for row2 in cursor:
        if row2[0] == None or row2[0] == ' ':
            row2[0] = de_objet
            cursor.updateRow(row2)

del row2

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_featureClass,["de_sou"]) as cursor:
    for row3 in cursor:
        if row3[0] == None or row3[0] == ' ':
            row3[0] = de_source
            cursor.updateRow(row3)
del row3

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_featureClass,["co_sou"]) as cursor:
    for row4 in cursor:
        if row4[0] == None or row4[0] == ' ':
            row4[0] = coDate
            cursor.updateRow(row4)
del row4
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_featureClass,["de_rem"]) as cursor:
    for row5 in cursor:
        if row5[0] == None or row5[0] == ' ':
            row5[0] = de_remarque
            cursor.updateRow(row5)
del row5



arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_featureClass,"co_ver","'V'" + strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'"),"PYTHON_9.3","")
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for the insights and explanations.  The script now works perfectly.  It doesn't surprise me that I could shorten my code and make it more efficient (you should have seen the first drafts) but at this point I'm still figuring out some of the basics in Arcpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're checking if 2 strings are equal, it's usually best to ensure that case sensitivity won't impact your results. As it so happens, the string returned by `arcpy.Describe().shapetype` is not in uppercase; it's actually in title case. But since you're not interested in the case of either, just convert the type to upper case:

```py
type = arcpy.Describe(in_featureClass).shapetype.upper()
if type == "POINT":
   #Code
```

Edit:

Your code can be shortened a great, great deal by just capitalizing the first letter of each string instead of all those if..elif statements. Furthermore, you can consolidate all those cursors into one. Just pass all the fields into the cursor. You might have to `zip()` the variables you're feeding to the cursor, but it's quite simple.

Edit2:

Instead of using all those if..elif statements, the following should do the same:

```py
ClasseAbrev = ClasseTemp.capitalize()
```

That's nearly 50 lines of code replaced with 1. `str.capitalize()` only changes the first letter in a string as opposed to `str.title()` which capitalizes each word.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "capitalizing the first letter of each string" - how does that shorten the code?  This was my first successful use of cursors and I'm still experimenting with their functionality but I will look into how to consolidate them as you suggest.

Comment: @Frederic, see my 2nd edit. That should help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(in_featureClass)
for row in cur:
    row.xDD = row.SHAPE.extent.XMin
    row.yDD = row.SHAPE.extent.YMin
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

It doesn't matter if you use XMin or XMax - as these are the same for points.